# PySide/PyQt: PointingHandCursor recipes?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a pyside application with a numerous buttons, toolbuttons, tabs etc... I would like all of them to have a 'pointing hand' cursor when hovering/clicking. This means my code is full of statements like this:

```
someWidget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
```

It is a relatively long, ugly line. 
I can encapsulate the above in a function:

```
def hand_cursor(widget):
    widget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
```

This makes the rest of the code somewhat neater:

```
hand_cursor(someWidget)
```

But I still have to write that line all over the place.

Does anyone know of a recipe/trick to be able to get all my buttons, tab bars etc to have the pointing hand cursor without repeating myself all over?

Answer (score 1):

I would maintain a list of all the widgets for which you want this behaviour, and loop:

```
widgetsToChange = [someWidget, anotherWidget, ...]
for w in widgetsToChange:
  hand_cursor(w) 
  #or w.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
```

You can also use `QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.WaitCursor))` to change for all the application.